# KnockoutJs 1.3 beta. _destroy:false has same result on ui as _destroy:true

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, destroy, knockout-mapping-plugin

Using asp.net mvc, I am passing a viewmodel down and getting knockout to map a viewmodel and bind to this.

This is all working fine for me, what i am trying to do is track deletions.

I thought i would be able to do this by adding the _destroy property but setting it to false.

I hoped that the ui would then ignore this until destroy set it to true.

But this does not seem to be the case and the mere presence of this property is causing to be treated as destroyed.

Is this a bug or am I handling this wrong?

Many thanks,
Kohan

```
  var model = [{"Id":1,"Name":"Bikes","Parent":null,"_destroy":false},
  {"Id":2,"Name":"Components","Parent":null,"_destroy":false},
  {"Id":3,"Name":"Clothing","Parent":null,"_destroy":false},
  {"Id":4,"Name":"Accessories","Parent":null,"_destroy":false},
  {"Id":5,"Name":"Mountain Bikes","Parent":1,"_destroy":false},
  {"Id":6,"Name":"Road Bikes","Parent":1,"_destroy":false},
  {"Id":7,"Name":"Touring Bikes","Parent":1,"_destroy":false},
  {"Id":8,"Name":"Handlebars","Parent":2,"_destroy":false}] ;
```

None of the above elements will show. Even "_destroy": null has the same effect.

### Working example of the problem...

### http://jsfiddle.net/jy53e/6/

Update: Seems to be an issue with the mapping extension.

Comment: Do you have a sample?  There might be something else at play.  Here is a working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/jy53e/

Comment: Thanks, i'm trying to get it to reproduce there.

Comment: This is what i have, it does not seem to work on JSFiddle at all unfortunately. http://jsfiddle.net/jy53e/3/

Comment: You had a bad reference to the mapping plugin (need the raw version on github): http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/jy53e/4/

Comment: Great, sorted thanks. updated question with working example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is happening is that you are sending `_destroy` through the mapping plugin and it is coming out as an observable.  Knockout does not expect it to be an observable (a function), so when it does a check like `if (_destroy)` the result will be true, because `_destroy` is a function and it is not unwrapped to see its value.

You can do something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/jy53e/7/ to prevent `_destroy` from getting made into an observable.

So, use mapping options:

```
var mappingOptions = {
    create: function(options) {
        return ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, { copy: ["_destroy"] }); 
    }
};
```

Comment: That does work, thanks, but makes the viewmodel look very messy. I am curious, why does http://jsfiddle.net/jy53e/10/ not work? According to the documentation it should.

Comment: I have also noticed that none of these examples that we have made work in ie-9. Is that a jsfiddle issue do you know?

Comment: IE9 blocks scripts that do not have the right mime type.  Github does not serve them up as scripts, because they are not really supposed to be hosting scripts for live use.  I agree that the fiddle that you posted should work based on the docs.  I found that it is comparing "_destroy" with like "[0]._destroy" when it is going through the array. Potentially a bug or shortcoming with the mapping plugin.